# Python creating files inside directories and deleting directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling, directory-structure

I'm practicing for a controlled assessment at home, and one of the steps that I find necessary is to create a folder for several different people, and should the need arise to reuse the program, to delete them. I tried to incorporate these things together in order to make the program more efficient, but I end up getting the

> "Failed. Aborting operation."

output instead of correctly using the singular except that I was expecting when the directories already exist. Additionally, the text file I am practicing this with will not appear inside the directory.

```
mSelect = int(input("Menu:\n 1. Initialize system (reset or prepare)\n 2. Input scores 
\n 3. Select which contestants go through. \n 4. Give a summary of the round"))
if mSelect == 1:
    print("Initializing systems")
    import os


for x in range(0,6):
    try:
        os.makedirs("couple"+str(x+1))
        tFileLocation = ("couple"+str(x+1))
        file = open("./"+tFileLocation+"/tScore.txt","w")
        file.close()
    except:
        print("Failed to create folder for couple:",x+1)
        print("Retrying...")
        try:
            os.remove(tFileLocation)
            os.makedirs("./"+tFileLocation)
            file = open("./"+tFileLocation+"/tScore.txt","w")
            file.close()
        except:
            print("Failed. Aborting operation")

for x in range(0,5):
    try:
        os.makedirs("judge"+str(x+1))
        file
    except:
        print("Failed to create folder for judge:",x+1)
    `
```

Above is the code I used for the menu selection as well as the initialization of the program. Any help would be appreciated, and an explanation for what I have done wrong would be a godsend.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, I'll double check that.

Comment: What is the full output if you replace `print("Failed. Aborting operation")` by `raise`?

Comment: traceback.print_exc() inside exception handler shows the full traceback to retrieve detailed information

Comment: @mkrieger1 if you mean that I should use just raise instead of the print, then it is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents/111 SCHOOL WORK/Year 11/Computer Science/NEA PRAC/BASE.py", line 19, in <module>
    os.makedirs("couple"+str(x+1))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\os.py", line 269, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'couple1'
(continued in next comment

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bladezy/Documents/111 SCHOOL WORK/Year 11/Computer Science/NEA PRAC/BASE.py", line 27, in <module>
    os.remove(tFileLocation)
NameError: name 'tFileLocation' is not defined

Comment: Ah, I think I found it. I didn't define tFileLocation in the exception part, since it simply tried it instead of commiting to saving it. Thanks for all the support.